# Why I get error while trying to attached debugging process to a Microsoft Azure app service?

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I am working on Azure Cloud , I have many APP services which i can explore from my visual studio by clicking View in the tool bar and select Cloud explorer .

I opened visual studio on the project that contains my API which i want to debug it remotely , then i had set break points in the places i want to hit .

Then i clicked View on the visual studio top menu and selected Cloud explorer , then it opened all the services which are on the Azure cloud . i selected the required service and clicked right click , then selected Attach Debugger , but it keeps giving me an Exception as you can see in the attached image .

I tried to turn off the fire wall and checked that the remote debugging is enabled on the required App service and it was enabled , but couldn't debug the service successfully ..

I had tried to debug other services rather than this one and it worked successfully , anyone have an idea on a similar issue ?

find the attached image for the error details and the line that scratched by black contains the app service name on Azure

[image]

Comment: Can you attach the image? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Remote debugging is enabled for the correction version of VS (2019) and app bitness is correctly selected (32 vs 64 bit). Take a look at the screenshot for the steps: 
[image]

[image]

Also, ensure that you have the latest SDK (https://azure.microsoft.com/downloads/) installed and all the Prerequisites (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet#prerequisites) are met. Close and re-open VS as ‘Run as administrator’ and then check to see if it helps. If feasible, restart the app and then check again and let us know for further investigation.

As mentioned in the [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2016/02/09/manually-attach-a-debugger-to-azure-web-apps/) check on how to attach the process manually.